# Getting 'ConvertBack(...)' to fire on WPF ComboBox selection change

Tags: wpf, combobox, ivalueconverter

I have a `ComboBox` with its `Items` property bound to a collection of objects. I also have `SelectedItem` property bound to the entire collection, with a `ValueConverter` designed to examine the elements in the collection and return the 1 item to be selected. This part works.

What doesn't work is when the user makes a selection change on the ComboBox, the `ConvertBack(...)` method of the `ValueConverter` is not being called. I need `ConvertBack(...)` called because I need to take the user's selection, re-examine the collection, and edit the old selected item and newly selected item appropriately.

I know this approach is a awkward, but it's the way it is. Here's the relevant code:

ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=DataInputAssetChoiceSelectedItemConverter}}" />
```

ValueConverter:

```
public class DataInputAssetChoiceSelectedItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            foreach (CustomObject Choice in (Collection<CustomObject>)value)
            {
                if (Choice.IsSelected)
                {
                    return Choice;
                }
            }
            return ((Collection<CustomObject>)value).First();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {   //breakpoint...execution never gets here!
        return null;
    }
}
```

So why doesn't `ConvertBack(...)` ever get called? Is it just something I'm misunderstanding about `ComboBox`? I've tried this approach using `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, `SelectedIndex`, and have tried messing with `UpdateSourceTrigger`, various binding modes, DataTriggers, and can never seem to get `ConvertBack(...)` to be called. Is using the `SelectionChanged` event the only option? If so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not binding to a property, so the Binding can't set anything. You are binding directly to the DataContext object, and the Binding won't update that.

If you had `{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Converter=...}` then the ConvertBack would be called. As it stands though, it won't be called.

Comment: Thanks for this tidbit. Based on this behavior, perhaps using DataContext as a source for a Binding should be disallowed since it can't fully participate in the Binding. I guess I'll have to use the SelectionChanged event and edit the contents of the DataCollection from there. Either that or change the data model so I can bind to an actual property...but that will be scary.

Comment: Marked as answer because you explained why ConvertBack(...) doesn't work for this particular situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it is awkward, but only because you're trying to add some management to the collection in a value converter instead of on the collection itself. I think it would help if your collection was more aware that its items have an `IsSelected` property:

```
public CustomCollection : Collection<CustomObject> {
    CustomObject _current;
    public CustomObject CurrentSelection {
        get { return _current; }
        set {
            if (_current == value)
                return;

            if (_current != null)
                _current.IsSelected = false;

            if (value != null)
                value.IsSelected = true;

            _current = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Just add a little extra to make sure that `_current` is at least the first element in the collection.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelection}">
```

Now you shouldn't need the converter anymore. There are some considerations missing, however. You may want to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when `CurrentSelection` is changed, so that if anything else is bound to that property or it changed in code, all bindings will update appropriately.

**Edit**: Wrapping the model

One easy way to wrap the collection instead of making a custom collection like above:

```
public class CollectionWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (o,e)=>{};
    // never have to check for null

    public CollectionWrapper(Collection<CustomObject> collection) {
        Items = collection;
    }

    // unlikely to change, so let's prevent it for now
    public Collection<CustomObject> Items {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    CustomObject _current;
    public CustomObject CurrentSelection {
        get { return _current; }
        set {
            if (_current == value)
                return;

            if (_current != null)
                _current.IsSelected = false;

            if (value != null)
                value.IsSelected = true;

            _current = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentSelection"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then this object becomes your data context and the `ComboBox` bindings change to this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelection}">
```

Comment: Yes, changing the data model is probably the best solution, but not easy in the current context. Perhaps I'll make a superfluous "wrapper" class for this collection for this particular binding.